# What is the PagesController in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am new to laravel and trying to learn it.

I came across this code which is declared in routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('about', function () {
    $joe = ["hi","this","is","about","us"];
    return view('about',['joe'=>$joe]);
});

Route::get('services', function () {
    $joe = ["hi","this","is","about","us"];
    return view('services');
});
```

but in another example they declared like this:

```
Route::get('/','PageController@welcome');
Route::get('/',PagesController@about');
```

I am new to laravel framework.

Comment: do spend some time reading documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Controller is responsible for controlling the application logic and acts as the coordinator **between the View and the Model**. The Controller receives an input from the users via the **View**, then processes the user's data with the help of **Model** and passes the results back to the **View**.

[More Info ( Laravel Controller )](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers)

You can rewrite your code as follow :

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index);
```

**MainController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

Read more about **MVC** design pattern
[More Info ( MVC )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)